# Why is $A=\{\frac{m}{2^n} \mid m, n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad 1\leq m\leq 2^n-1\}$ dense in [0, 1]?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am stuck on this problem

> Why is $A=\{\frac{m}{2^n} \mid m, n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad 1\leq m\leq 2^n-1\}$ dense in $[0, 1]$?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n = \{ {m \over 2^n} | 1 \le m \le 2^n -1 \}$.

If $x \in [0,1]$, what is $\inf  \{ |x-y| | y \in A_n \}$?

Comment: A better wording might be to ask what is an upper bound for the $\inf$ over all $x$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for each $n$, write $[0,1)$ as $\bigcup_{m=0}^{2^n-1}\left[\frac m{2^n},\frac{m+1}{2^n}\right)$.